# clear a cell based on the contents of another cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have on a google spreadsheet on the sheet "SUIVI ANIM", a column Y whose each cell contains from line 5, a drop-down menu. Then I have in column Z a small "x". I would like that when in column Y, it is "Submit LEAD" which is selected that automatically the small "x" of column Z is erased.
For example, if "Submit LEAD" in Y3 then Z3 is empty. If "Submit LEAD" in Y4 then Z4 empties etc.

I searched and found this script:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  // identify the range and values to watch and clear
  var watchCol = 25; // Column Y
  var watchValue = "Submit LEAD";
  var clearCol = 26; // Column Z
  // 

  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the column = "+e.range.columnStart+", and the value = "+e.value)
  if (e.range.columnStart === watchCol && e.value === watchValue) {
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the conditions were met");   
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, clearCol).clearContent()
  }
  return false;
}
```

But it doesn't work and the debug tells me it's wrong from the line: `if (e.range.columnStart === watchCol && e.value === watchValue) {`

I'm new to scripting and I'm French so sorry if I'm not very clear.

Thanks for any help you could give me.
émilie

Comment: I think your trying to run this from the script editor.  That won't work because e is undefined.

Comment: yes it is a script in Apps Script.
How can I define "e"? Is there another solution ?

Comment: The onEdit(event) runs from the Spreadsheet context.  When the user edits a cell on the sheet the onEdit(event) is triggered and "event" is the event object that contains information on the edit cell.   Instead of Logger.log use ss.toast and see what your DEBUG comments are.

Comment: e is just a parameter that is filled with the event object by the trigger.  People use e because it's less work to type e rather than event

Answer (score 0):

#### You cannot return anything to a trigger

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 25 && e.value == "Submit LEAD") {
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 26).clearContent();
  }
}
```

Normally people put a sheet name in the conditional so that it only runs on selected sheets.